# Password Manager no longer works with Password field after redesign

Tags: html, passwords

i have redesigned our company page, and per our design agencies recommendation, went with no labels for our fields, so I have these fields below:

```
<input type="text" name="userid" value="User ID" />
<input type="text" name="passFake" value="Password" />
<input type="password" name="passReal" value="" />
```

So when the user enters the page, the "fake" password field is visible, and the "real" password field is hidden, and the user sees two fields with the labels, essentially, inside the fields.  Using Javascript, i'm able to hide the fake password field on focus and show the real password field so that users are entering their password in the password field.

However, with users who use password managers, and have previously recorded their passwords on our site, are experiencing an issue.  I suspect that the Password manager tools are modifying the field via javascript without setting the focus, so they are just populating the user's password in the fake password field.

This had two side effects:

- User's password is displaying because it's being inputted into the "text" field, not the password field
- User's not able to login because the password is being put into the wrong field

I can't install the password manager on my home machine, as it's not allowed on company computers, so can I just assume that if I attach a onchange event to the fake password field?   Or is my assumption on how the password managers work incorrect?

Comment: What is this for in the first place? I don't understand. Why two fields?

Comment: when a user first enters the page, for all intents and purposes, the field labels are inside the fields.

Comment: ah, I see now. But I can't see a reason for a password manager to fill the fake field. What happens if you change the fields' order in the markup? (If that is possible - not sure)

Comment: it sounds like you will introduce serious security issues. Apart of that having the javascript and the css codes could help understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing HTML markup to create a presentational effect can bite you later.

Why not create labels for your inputs as normal, place them on top of your inputs via CSS, then set to hide them on click or when the input receives focus? That should take care of the issues with password managers, since their won't be a fake field there to get in the way.

I put together an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hellslam/jk5Bv/10/

Comment: Thanks for including the JS example with your response.  Without the link, I probably would've not understood your answer and might have dismissed you response as you not know what i asked for.  Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Additionally, I'll probably have to push the labels to the left (instead of hide) to keep them accessible.